# Is it possible to bind object field directly in Svelte 3?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-2

Is there a way to bind object field in Svelte 3?

Example:

```html
<script>
  import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.svelte"
  let myobjectID
</script>

<MyComponent bind:myobject[id]={myobjectID}>

<!-- Where myobject == {id: "123", name: "myName", and so on...} -->
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I am dealing with similar issue, in the object oriented approach I did not find any other better than Angular - cleaner and well designed even DI from the beginning. For years trying to find other alternatives... none better than A. If you are an OOP dev, that is the only best option you have. Otherwise you will find yourself using shortcuts and tricks for simple things.

Answer (score 5):

No there isn't.

If you want `MyComponent` to work internally with an object, but only allow the consumer to change a specific part of that object you *could* do as follows:

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
  import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.svelte"
  let myobjectID
</script>

<MyComponent bind:id={myobjectID} />
```

**MyComponent.svelte**

```html
<script>
    export let id
    $: myobject = {
        id,
        name: 'myName'
    }
</script>
```

But a more generic way where you would be able to do this way *any* property of `myobject` does not exist, in that case you're better off not using an object internally for your component and just constructing it as an object when you need it.

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in way in svelte to do that, but here's a workaround:

```
<script>
    import MyComponent from './MyComponent.svelte';
    let myobjectID = 1;
    $: myObject = {...myObject, id: myobjectID}
</script>
<MyComponent bind:myobject={myObject} />
```

The solution is to create a reactive statement that takes all `myobject` properties and assign them to `myObject` local variable in the App.svelte, and assign the `id` property afterwards, which then will bind to the `myobject` and have it changes as `myobjectID` changes.